# Connect to POP3S server in linux

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-mail, pop3, dovecot

I want to connect to a POP3S (SSL security) server in linux(the pop3 server is dovecot). I tried with normal sockets but it doesn't work(i get no reply from server) new Socket("localhost", 995). I found this command searching on the internet: "openssl s_client -connect localhost:995" and it works from terminal (+OK Dovecot ready.). Any solutions? (with or without java.mail library) i prefer without java.mail, but its also good with it. Thanks!

Comment: *Without* Javamail? Are you prepared to write your own implementation of the POP3 protocol using SSLSockets?

Comment: I would try...any suggestions or help?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting no reply from the server when creating your own Socket because you're not creating an SSLSocket.

Try JavaMail, it should work fine.  Start at the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html).